# Javascript slideshow not working; works locally but not when uploaded

Tags: javascript, html, web, slideshow

As the title suggests, the slideshow works locally but not when it's uploaded to the server.

The website is http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/photos.html

The slideshow code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-->
    var image1=new Image()
    image1.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2509.jpg"
    var image2=new Image()
    image2.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2510.jpg"
    var image3=new Image()
    image3.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2518.jpg"
    var image4=new Image()
    image4.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2536.jpg"
    var image5=new Image()
    image5.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg"
    var image6=new Image()
    image6.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg"
    var image7=new Image()
    image7.src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2543.jpg"
//-->
</script>
<img src="images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2509.jpg" name="slide" width="450" height="300"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    var step=1
    function slideit(){
        document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src")
        if(step<6)
            step++
        else
            step=1
        setTimeout("slideit()",3000)
    }
    slideit();
//-->
</script>
```

Anyone have any idea or reason for why it is not working?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Open up your console and you'll see why.

Comment: Excuse me for my ignorance but I'm fairly new to this and do not know what "console" means when referring to this.

Comment: Are you sure your images are in the right place? "images/ESL Keep/Thumbnails/"

Answer (score 0):

Your photos are missing see site errors:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2509.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2510.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2518.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2536.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2543.jpg
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2510.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2518.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2536.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2509.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2510.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2518.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2536.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
GET http://cmp.physics.iastate.edu/esl/images/ESL%20Keep/Thumbnails/IMG_2537.jpg 404 (Not Found) photos.html:78
```

Ensure your pictures are in the correct location for images to show.

I found this from the [Console feature in Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console), may I please suggest using this to develop and test sites.

Comment: @user2876702 no worries, if it is your answer please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Theck your javascript source file inclusion at in the body tag, You might have two jquery files included. I also faced this issue, it worked on my localhost but not on the live server, then i removed the second qquery inclusion and it started working.

I hope this works

Example:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--find the second jquery file and remove it-->
    </body
```